# Firebase Authentication: auth/auth-domain-config-required

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting auth-domain-config-required errors when using `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)`.

I've tried with Google and Facebook. I've tested on my hosted site, and it works fine. You can test it live: [Quiver Chat Demo](https://quiver-four.firebaseapp.com/)

I suspect there's a problem with localhost:3333... does it not like my port? I can't add a port to the ***Authorized domains*** list, and adding it to my `authDomain:` config doesn't help either.

Here's my auth code, but as you can see from the screenshots below, I tried a bunch of different `authDomain` values.

```
  <script src="https://quiver-four.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/4.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://quiver-four.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/4.6.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCzNxnQ6WCJKejq6SBd7NqhVskxEOmDq_Y",
      authDomain: "quiver-four.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://quiver-four.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "quiver-four",
      storageBucket: "quiver-four.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "1082528354495"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
```

---

## Attempting localhost:3333

[image: Attempting localhost:3333]

---

## Attempting localhost

[image: Just localhost]

---

## Attempting quiver-four.firebaseapp.com

[image: quiver-four.firebaseapp.com, as copied from the Firebase console]

---

## The domains are added

[image]

Comment: Hey Chris. Can you edit your question to include the code of how you initialize the Firebase app? My first guess is that something's going wrong there.

Comment: Hey Frank, I tried three varieties and copied them all up.

Comment: Have you been able so solve this? Facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

You must not be providing the correct `authDomain` in your Firebase app initialization configuration.
You can get that web snippet from the Firebase Console. The `authDomain` has the form `projectName.firebaseapp.com`.

Comment: Sorry. I tried that, and I tried to link to screenshots... but they didn't go up on my first post. I've edited the question to make it explicit.

Comment: I checked your site. I am not getting the error you are describing but I am noticing the error in sign in with redirect due to your service worker messing with pages under /__/auth/... which are managed by Firebase Auth team and required to complete sign-in. Please remove that path from your service worker caching.

Comment: Yeah. I've seen the same issue with the serviceWorker. That was a quick demo site, so I just deleted the worker for the demo :) The problem is that auth doesn't work on localhost. My point is that it works fine on Firebase hosting but doesn't work on localhost.

Comment: The setup should be exactly the same whether localhost or production site. I can't debug your issue if you can't get your sample app working.

Comment: OP is correct in setting `authDomain` to their custom URL according to [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices) (related to sign-in with popup and redirects). If your web-application is not hosted under `name.firebase.com` you'll have to do some of the steps described in the article. However, as OP mentions, firebase does not like us specifying ports for whatever reason..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and my solution was to have a file in the root firebase.js with all the connection configuration:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth'

import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxx_xxx_R-xxx-CDxxxxcg",
  authDomain: "qxxxxxx-xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxxxxx-xxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxx-xxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxx",
  appId: "1:xxxxxxx:wxb:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  measurementId: "G-xxxxx"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```