# Troubleshooting the 'auth/auth-domain-config-required' error when using Firebase social sign in with Next.js app on localhost

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, localhost, google-oauth

I am developing a simple app with NextJS 13 (**testing locally on localhost:3001**) and I have ran into a problem that seems to not be very well documented anywhere online.

I have set up the Firebase JS SDK in my project and want to use it to allow users to register and sign in using both password and social authentication. On my login page I have a form where I can enter an email address and password and a submit button which calls the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` function from the SDK. This works perfectly and Firebase successfully logs in the user and saves their details to local storage.

The problem arises when I try to do the same thing using the GoogleAuthProvider from the same SDK. Every time I click on my "Sign in with Google" button, I get the following error in the console:

```
dex-e3d5d3f4.js:497 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/auth-domain-config-required).
    at createErrorInternal (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:610:41)
    at _assert (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:616:15)
    at getIframeUrl (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:9429:5)
    at _openIframe (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:9454:14)
    at async BrowserPopupRedirectResolver.initAndGetManager (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-e3d5d3f4.js:9720:24)
```

My Firebase config (env values are straight from the admin console) looks like this:

```ts
// /src/lib/auth.ts

import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId:
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// gives us an auth instance
const auth = getAuth(app);

// in order to use this auth instance elsewhere
export default auth;
```

Here is my login page code (minimal example, styles and non functional parts removed):

```tsx
// /src/app/login/page.tsx

"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signInWithPopup,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "firebase/auth";

import auth from "@/lib/auth";

export default function Page() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  async function handleFormSubmit(e: React.FormEvent) {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      alert("Failed to sign in");
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} className="mt-8 space-y-6">
        <input
          id="email-address"
          name="email"
          type="email"
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          id="password"
          name="password"
          type="password"
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
      <button
        onClick={async () => {
          await signInWithPopup(auth, new GoogleAuthProvider());
        }}
      >
        Login with google
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

**What I have tried**

- I checked my Firebase authorized domain configuration to make sure that localhost is on the allowed list - it is.

[Firebase authorized domains list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5x9a.png)

- I tried to specifically add localhost:3001 to the allowed domains list, but it does not let me specify a port
- I changed the authDomain in my Firebase config in /src/lib/auth.ts to "localhost", which stopped the error from happening, but introduced another one: the pop up window does not correctly open to the sign in page, and instead throws a SSL error:

[Popup window error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FoGE.png)

- The solutions from [Firebase Authentication: auth/auth-domain-config-required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47353822/firebase-authentication-auth-auth-domain-config-required) - exported the auth object from a file and checked allowed domains, no success.

**What I'm expecting**

The social sign in to work the same way as email/password - correctly authenticating and signing in the user on the client side.